# C: searching an array and returning multiple values

Tags: c, arrays, search

I'm working on a sample from my textbook regarding 2 dimensional arrays. It has the following example that allows the user to input a value, and then it searches the array and returns the location of the element that contains the value, or alerts them if the value doesn't exist.

What I'm wondering, is what if multiple elements contain the user's value? In the code, I added some loops to initialize the 2d array, and multiple elements contain the same value. How would I set up the search that it would return multiple elements as containing the search value?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int iTwoD[3][3];
int iFoundAt[2] = {0};
int x, y;
int iFound, iValue = 0;


//initialize the 2-d array
for ( x = 0; x<=2; x++) {

  for (y=0;y<=2;y++)
    iTwoD[x][y] = (x+y);
} //end outer loop

//print the 2-d array
for (x=0; x<=2; x++){

  for (y=0;y<=2;y++)
    printf("iTwoD[%d][%d] = %d\n", x, y, iTwoD[x][y]);

}//end outer loop

//Get the user's value to search for
printf("\nEnter your search value: ");
scanf("%d", &iValue);

//Search the 2-d array for user's value
for (x = 0; x<=2; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y<=2; y++) {
    if ( iTwoD[x][y] == iValue) {
      iFound = 1;
      iFoundAt[0] = x;
      iFoundAt[1] = y;
      break;
    } //end if
  } //end inner loop
} //end outer loop

if (iFound ==1)
  printf("\nFound value in iTwoD[%d][%d]\n", iFoundAt[0], iFoundAt[1]);
else
  printf("\nValue not found\n");

return 0;
} //end main
```

Comment: Use an array to store the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( iTwoD[x][y] == iValue)
{
   arrayOfResults[i][0]=resultx;
   arrayOfResults[i++][1]=resulty;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't stop the loop after finding a single result, but keeps going until the end of 2d array and stores all the correct results in an array

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to increase your `iFoundAt` to be able to hold more than a single tuple of (x,y). In addition, you'll need to remove the `break` from the search since you need to search the entire matrix despite the found value.